# Switch paragraph using inner html

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm trying to change an image in one div and the paragraph text in another div when somebody clicks on a specific co-ordinate on my map.

My current code:

**JS**

```
function myFunction(location_01)
{document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "location 1 - paragraph 1";}
{document.getElementById("overview").innerHTML = "overview 1 - paragraph 1";}
{document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = "distance 1 - paragraph 1";}

function myFunction(location_02)
{document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "location 2 - paragraph 2";}
{document.getElementById("overview").innerHTML = "overview 2 - paragraph 2";}
{document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = "distance 2 - paragraph 2";}

// etc
```

**HTML**

```
<area shape="circle" coords="421,483,13" href="#" alt="alt1"
onclick="MM_swapImage('pic_01','','pic1.png',1)";"myFunction('location_01')" />
<area shape="circle" coords="395,475,12" href="#" alt="alt2"
onclick="MM_swapImage('pic_01','','pic2.png',1)","myFunction('location_02')"/>
```

My images are changing fine but my paragraph change is not seeming to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're closing your braces too early and only need one function.

```
function myFunction(num)
{
    num = parseInt(num);
    document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = "location " + num + " - paragraph " + num;
    document.getElementById("overview").innerHTML = "overview " + num + " - paragraph " + num;
    document.getElementById("distance").innerHTML = "distance " + num + " - paragraph " + num;
}
```

Also fix the following quotes:

```
<area shape="circle" coords="421,483,13" href="#" alt="alt1" onclick="MM_swapImage('pic_01','','pic1.png',1);myFunction('01')" />
<area shape="circle" coords="395,475,12" href="#" alt="alt2" onclick="MM_swapImage('pic_01','','pic2.png',1),myFunction('02')"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. It still doesn't seem to be working... I'm placing my javascript in the head of my html. I'm assuming that's fine.

Comment: `myFunction` is declared twice... I assume that is not what you want. You are not using the parameter passed in either.

Comment: Thank you - that's still not working for me although I didn't add the num - parseInt(num) as the paragraph I'm wanting to show is actually different to 'paragraph 1' - each paragraph is quite lengthy so I was just trying to simplify it for the example i.e. my text won't follow a numerical order. Is there something else I've missed? My images still work fine...